# SASS File Structuring: Same Selector in _typography, _layout, etc

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

i feel like this may be simple enough and I'm just missing it. I recently went to 7-1 folder structure instead of a single scss file. What i'm having difficulty with is referencing .panel(or h2 or span) in _typography.scss to do font-styling and reference the same .panel(h2,span, etc) in my _layout.scss.

I understand from a CSS pov this wouldn't be logical to have them broken up as of sequencing, however, from a sass pov, I feel like there should be a way to structure this so my CSS doesn't have .nav-container mentioned twice.

Just to note, I'm using NPM, not an ide compiler. Maybe I'm just going about structuring generally incorrect and shouldn't separate them.

Please advise,

**UPDATE ANSWER**
I've marked Frish's answer here correct because the way that they set it up is correct, but after several and i mean several days of research, i've decided to add some context as I see many others have created simiar threads.

1. The way I initially looked at SASS was incorrect. I was trying to make SASS work in a way i thought would eliminate complexity: *(having .nav-container {} typography rules in a typography partial, then .nav-container {} layout in a layout partial.)* This isn't the right way of thinking.
2. The real benefits are all the built in functions (placeholders,mixins, extends) that drive the magic of making SASS more effective.

However, there is a way to still do what you're looking to do, styling selectors across different partials, for example, separating typography styling from layout styling, and so forth, for particular selector. This was a major wakeup call. **Passing Style Blocks (or Content Blocks) to a mixin or whatever.** So for example:

```
@mixin button {  
 font-size: 1em;  
 padding: 0.5em 1.0em;  
 text-decoration: none;  
 color: #fff;  
 @content;  
}

.button-green {  
 @include button {  
   background: green  
 }
}
```

Finally,

1. this link(https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/5625786-produce-maintainable-css-with-sass/5951856-write-cleaner-code-with-sass-extensions) is where it really clicked for me
2. Look at the section paragraph that starts with **"extensions are a lot like mixins."** Review this example as it should be easy to apply its setup and way of structuring to what you're trying to do.
3. Getting deeper into this, i did some googling on "passing style blocks" and "sass passing content blocks" and that helped a ton on how to leverage placeholders, mixins, and extends effectively while still maintaining the simplicity of sass structuring.

Comment: Also if there's a more appropriate way to do this with extend or mixin across files, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a concrete answer as there are many ways to approach this (as you are undoubtedly aware), but here are my thoughts.

I typically use generic stylesheets (_typography, _layout) for generic elements (h1,h2,h3, .section, .container perhaps). Any element that merits special mention in multiple files potentially merits being its own component (e.g. panel.scss).

This does increase the numbers of folders and files floating around, but I still find this preferable to one, or a few, big files. I usually end up with a `main.scss` file that looks like this:

```
// main.scss
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "_typography.scss"; 
// etc....

@import "./components/panel.scss";
@import "./components/navContainer.scss"; // or, nav-container.scss!
// etc....
```

Components happily override generic styles, and I can track their CSS in individual files. Happy dev! You can sub-divide components or other files as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks fortthe reply. I've considered the recommendation. I do feel a property such as h2 {
  display: inline; } should be separated more gracefully from font styling properties, but not sure how to go about achieving this

Comment: Took me a few days but I appreciate your answers much more now. I've updated my original question to include context to what helped the most.

Comment: Happy to help! SCSS is like magic CSS :)